# What is ISA in EventQuery?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

Say I have a code:

```
public void StartThreadWatch()
{
    EventQuery query = new EventQuery
    ("SELECT * FROM _InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 " +
     "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";
     ManagementEventWatcher watcher =
        new ManagementEventWatch(query);
      watch.EventArrived += EventArrived;
      watch.Start();
 }
```

I don't know what is 'ISA' in the query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ISA` is an [operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) of the [`WQL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) language used to query the subclasses of a specified WMI class.

For more info check these msdn links

- [ISA Operator for Data Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391407(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [ISA Operator for Event Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391408(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [ISA Operator for Schema Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391409(v=vs.85).aspx)